# NETWORK_ERROR The provided session identifier or data is invalid

Tags: adyen

I try to integrate the Adyen Drop-in in a prototype.

After successful creating a session the sessionData is filled in a textarea with id="sessiondata".
Next I want to call the drop-in:

```
const configuration = {
    environment: 'test', // Change to one of the environment values specified in step 4.
    clientKey: 'test_***', // Public key used for client-side authentication: https://docs.adyen.com/development-resources/client-side-authentication
    analytics: {
          enabled: false // Set to false to not send analytics data to Adyen.
    },
    session: {
          id: $('#pcid').val(), // Unique identifier for the payment session.
          sessionData: $('#sessiondata').val() // The payment session data.
    },
    onPaymentCompleted: (result, component) => {
          console.info(result, component);
    },
    onError: (error, component) => {
          console.error(error.name, error.message, error.stack, component);
    },
  // Any payment method specific configuration. Find the configuration specific to each payment method:  https://docs.adyen.com/payment-methods
  // For example, this is 3D Secure configuration for cards:
    paymentMethodsConfiguration: {
        card: {
            hasHolderName: true,
            holderNameRequired: true,
            billingAddressRequired: true
        }
    }
};

// Create an instance of AdyenCheckout using the configuration object.
const checkout = await AdyenCheckout(configuration);
 
// Create an instance of Drop-in and mount it to the container you created.
const dropinComponent = checkout.create('dropin').mount('#dropin-container');
}
```

It returns with:

`tp.ts:50     POST https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/v1/sessions/***/setup?clientKey=test_*** 422 lj @ http.ts:50 sj @ http.ts:108 T3 @ setup-session.ts:19 value @ CheckoutSession.ts:63 value @ core.ts:46 (anonymous) @ index.ts:14 _ @ regeneratorRuntime.js:53 (anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:135 (anonymous) @ regeneratorRuntime.js:79 Qd @ asyncToGenerator.js:4 i @ asyncToGenerator.js:23 (anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:28 t @ export.js:18 (anonymous) @ asyncToGenerator.js:20 Y3 @ index.ts:15 (anonymous) @ index.ts:12 goDropin2 @ adyen.js:69 error @ adyen.js:32 c @ jquery.min.js:2 fireWith @ jquery.min.js:2 l @ jquery.min.js:2 (anonymous) @ jquery.min.js:2 load (async) send @ jquery.min.js:2 ajax @ jquery.min.js:2 S.<computed> @ jquery.min.js:2 goDropin @ adyen.js:3 onclick @ VM28 Adyen-Start:1 adyen.js:55 NETWORK_ERROR The provided session identifier or data is invalid. NETWORK_ERROR: The provided session identifier or data is invalid.     at cj (https://checkoutshopper-test.adyen.com/checkoutshopper/sdk/5.39.0/adyen.js:1:198100)`

How can I find out, what data is invalid?

Can anyone help please?

Answer (score 1):

The session id in the configuration for drop-in is not the reference for the sessions call. It's from the response ("id").

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).